# Find the convolution if OFGs

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

f(x) = **E** aj * (x^3)^j     ;     g(x) = **E** bj * (x^2)^j

Sorry for the format, with **E** I meant to type Sigma.
How do I find [x^k] (f(x)*g(x)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming 
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^{3j}\qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j x^{2j}
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^k]\left(f(x)\cdot g(x)\right)&=[x^k]\left(\sum_{p=0}^\infty a_px^{3p}\sum_{q=0}^\infty b_q x^{2q}\right)\\
> &=[x^k]\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{{3p+2q=n}\atop{p,q\geq 0}} a_pb_q x^n\right)\\
> &=\sum_{{3p+2q=k}\atop{p,q\geq 0}} a_pb_q
> \end{align*}